# How to remove a dict from a list of dicts based on whether a value is more than X months old

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which removes a `dict` from a `list` of `dict`s in Python based on whether the `Date` key has a value greater than 180 days ago (ideally needs to be 6 months):

```
gp_clinicals_meds_repeat = session["gp_clinicals_meds_repeat"]
for i in range(len(gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"])):
    date_object = parser.parse(gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"][i]["Date"])
    months_between = datetime.now() - date_object
    if months_between.days > 180:
        del gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"][i]
```

An example of my JSON is below (just has one entry but could have hundreds):

```
{
    "GpRepeatMedicationsList": [{
        "Constituent": "",
        "Date": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
        "Dosage": "0.6ml To Be Taken Each Day",
        "LastIssuedDate": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
        "MixtureId": "",
        "Quantity": "50",
        "ReadCode": "DADR8795BRIDL",
        "Rubric": "Dalivit oral drops (Dendron Brands Ltd)",
        "TenancyDescription": "Orglinks",
        "Units": "ml"
    }],
    "TotalItemCount": 1
}
```

I was thinking list comprehension but not sure how to parse the string as a date within it.

My code does not work correctly if it needs to remove two elements in a row, since it will always increment `i`, regardless of whether it just removed the element at index `i`. Also, it will keep running until the end of the original length, so if you remove any elements, this code will end with an exception because `gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"][i]` will no longer exist for the later values of `i`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Best not to delete while iterating. Just append the items to a new list if they pass your condition.

Comment: Changing the length of the list while you iterate over it is a bad idea. Use a list comprehension, as you were thinking, or filter the list. Maybe transform the date to an actual date earlier, when you're parsing the input.

Comment: It's better not to delete an item while iterating. Just use the `filter` function or a list comprehension to create a new one instead of mutating the initial.

Comment: How would I convert the string to a date object and then test to see if it fails/pass the test within a list comprehension?

Comment: To get 6 months rather than 180 days, use `dateutil.relativedelta`: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with an `if` to easily do this. I separated the criteria in a function since it may be a bit more complicated. I also recommend using `pandas.Timestamp` to handle dates, as it is very robust:

```py
import pandas as pd

def is_recent(entry):
    date_object = pd.to_datetime(entry["Date"])
    days_between = pd.Timestamp.today() - date_object
    return days_between < pd.Timedelta(days=180)

original_clinicals = gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"]
recent_clinicals = [entry for entry in original_clinicals if is_recent(entry)]
gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"] = recent_clinicals  # Replace the original list
```

To get 6 months instead of 180 days, you can use `dateutil.relativedelta`s. The `is_recent` function can be changed like (you could add a parameter to allow a configurable number of months).

```py
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.relativedelta as relativedelta

def is_recent(entry):
    limit_time = pd.Timestamp.today() - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=6)
    return pd.to_datetime(entry["Date"]) > limit_time

original_clinicals = gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"]
recent_clinicals = [entry for entry in original_clinicals if is_recent(entry)]
```

Comment: My strings are in the format `2012-01-31T00:00:00`. I get an error saying: `date_object = pd.to_datetime(entry["Date"])    TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: How are you calling the function? Did you use exactly the code I put there? This is not related to the conversion function, but you are not sending the dictionary as input.

Comment: The code assumes that `gp_clinicals_meds_repeat["GpRepeatMedicationsList"]` contains the list of dictionaries in the example in your question.

Comment: Sorted - realised as soon as I commented that was the issue - many thanks